# if condtion inside div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to do this condition inside the div to display the first word if isdeleted== true

```
  <div  style="display:inline-block;float:right;padding-right:10px;margin-right:10px;">
<%# Item.IsDeleted ? 'not active':'active' %>   </div>
```

page can recognize `Item` object only in this way `<%# Item.IsDeleted %>`
and can't recognize it in this way `<% if(Item.IsDeleted)%>`

Update:-
 what If I add

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenisdeleted" Value=" <%# Item.IsDeleted %>" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
```

How can I check value of the hidden field inside the Div tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Literal control:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; float: right; padding-right: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
    <asp:Literal ID="divContent" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.IsDeleted ? "not active": "active" %>' />
</div>
```

I assume that `Item` is defined and accessible in code-behind, and that it has an `IsDeleted` property.

If the div is not inside a databound control, you must call `divContent.DataBind()` to make sure that the databinding expression is evaluated:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        divContent.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work.

```
<div  style="display:inline-block;float:right;padding-right:10px;margin-right:10px;">
    <% if (Item.IsDeleted ) { %>
        not active
    <% }
    else { %>
          active
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't recognize the `Item.IsDeleted `

Answer (score 0):

It should be this like:

```
<% if(Item.IsDeleted == true){'not active'} else{'active'} %>
```

Comment: Can't recognize the `Item.IsDeleted `

Comment: @saraadly try to add Item.IsDeleted = true

Comment: can't regognize `Item` it self , but this way `<%# Item.IsDeleted%>`